How to find file names with non-printable characters using `find` on macOS?
Some folders on macOS have custom icons that are stored in a file named Icon?, where the ? is actually a CR character, and only prints as "?" in most cases (in Terminal and Finder).
But when printing such a file name in hex in Terminal, you'll get:
$ ls -l1 Icon* | xxd
00000000: 4963 6f6e 0d0a         Icon..

The 0d is the CR at the end of the name, and the 0a is the LF that's printed by ls at the end of each line.
Now, I like to find such files, using find.
I'd think that this would be the way:
find -E . -iregex ".*/Icon\x0d"

Nor does:
find -E . -iregex ".*/Icon\r"

However, this won't find it. But this finds it (using . as a wildcard char):
find -E . -iregex ".*/Icon."

But something is wrong with looking for hex chars in general, because this doesn't work either:
find -E . -iregex ".*/\x49con."

\x49 is the code for I, so this should work.
So, if you want to try this yourself, take any file and try to find it using the find command with the -regex option and specifying at least one character in hex, e.g. looking for the file named "a" with the regex \x61 or whatever is correct. Can you accomplish it?

I don't think the regexp engine parses hex escape sequences. Try putting a literal CR character in the regexp, using $'...'
find . -name $'Icon\r'

There's no need to use a regular expression, since you're just looking for a specific name, not a pattern.

The same also appears to work with the -regex option. Weird, but good enough for my needs. Also, if you could please upvote the question - some bozo keeps downvoting every question I ask on SO.

To be fair, this isn't really a programming question, so the downvote may be deserved.

good point - it used to be okay to ask shell questions on SO, but nowadays The unix specific subsites are probably the better choice. However, I use it in a program, so it's a programming issue for me :)
Plus, downvotes shall be explained in a comment. I think this is just general vandalism (either against me or against Mac specific questions)

What still bugs me is that, according to man find, the \x notation should work. I wonder if it needs special escaping when using it in a shell.

I suspect a documentation error. There are so many different regexp libraries....

Here's why this isn't a good solution for me: If the user would search using the RE .*/\w+\r, it wouldn't work with find on macOS. Oddly, though, the same works on a Synology NAS with gnu find 4.4.2.
Also, in my tests with gnu find, it also failed to find items when using \n or \x0d, and even piping all results from find into grep didn't work there, but works on macOS. What a mess

MacOS is running BSD find, not GNU find. It's not surprising they work differently.

Are you sure you read the MacOS version of the man page? https://ss64.com/mac/find.html doesn't mention \x at all (granted, it's probably an older version).

@tripleee It makes reference to the re_format(7) man page, which does mention it.

I'm going to accept this answer now because, surprisingly, it still even works with GNU find when combining with patterns such as \w (which means that $'' interprets only what it understands, e.g. \r, leaving the rest alone, thus \w gets passed to the command). This works for me for use on Linux, with a fallback to piping into egrep on the Mac instead, thereby making \w work on a Mac as well. (if you're curious, this is being used in Find Any File's upcoming Pro version that uses find for better performance).
